# Trouble connecting Microsoft Visual Studio with RDS AWS (C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, amazon-web-services, relational-database

I have trouble connecting to my database. This is my connectionstring (using mysql.data.mysqlclient)

```
        MySqlConnectionStringBuilder myBuilder = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        myBuilder.Database = "rds-mysql";
        myBuilder.Server = "rds-mysql.cnpzvlsgflgi.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com";
        myBuilder.Port = 3606;
        myBuilder.UserID = "username";
        myBuilder.Password = "****";

 MySqlConnection myconn = new MySqlConnection(myBuilder.ConnectionString);

        myconn.Open();
```

I even adjusted my security group to allow my IP address and turned off my firewalls but it still won't connect. 
Additional information: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts

Any help would be great, thank you.

Comment: Post the actual expression, not your interpretation of it. You can get the full exception with `Exception.ToString()`. The exception message isn't enough if there is an inner exception

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll